# How to setup Flow to monitor file changes with WebPack 2.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, flowtype

Is there a way to setup  [Flow](https://flow.org/en/)  to run with WebPack 2 watch. So that Flow would run a 'flow status' command on each WebPack successful build ?

Currently I tried:

**webpack-shell-plugin**.

It allows me to run shell commands before and after WebPacks build. But once a flow finds an error, it terminates the watch process.
code:

```
...
    plugins: [
        new WebpackShellPlugin({
          onBuildEnd:['npm run --silent flow']
        })
      ]
```

**flow-status-webpack-plugin**

For me it does not work. It doesn't produce nothing inside the console.

**flow-babel-webpack-plugin**

While this plugin did work, sadly on each build it restarts the flow server, making the flow type chasing extremely long. Also because of the server restart native flow support form Visual Studio Code and InteliJ stops working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue using

```
'flow-status-webpack-plugin'
```

the webpack.config looks like this:

```
var FlowStatusWebpackPlugin = require('flow-status-webpack-plugin');
{
  ...
  plugins: [
    new FlowStatusWebpackPlugin({
      onError: function(stdout) {
        console.log(stdout)
      },
      onSuccess: function(stdout){
        console.log(stdout)
      },
      restartFlow: false,
      failOnError: true,
      binaryPath: './node_modules/.bin/flow'
    })
  ]
}
```